# Setup server in phpMyAdmin 4.0 on Godaddy

Tags: phpmyadmin, shared-hosting

The GoDaddy's original phpMyAdmin version is 2.11 more than 10 years old.
So I decided to install version 4.0 on my own throuht FTP (as 4.7 needs PHP 5.5, and I have 5.4)

I'am trying to setup the server connection, but it doesn't work.
Tried to set **Direct Access** in GoDaddy's panel. Tried to enable **DSN**. But nothing happend.

I think that I am missing some configuration tuning...

Thanks for any assistance as I searched google and here, and didn't find any examples of proper configuration with **GoDaddy's Standart Windows Web Hosting**